# New CPU and bios doesn't work (m-flash too)

Tags: cpu, bios

My PC specs are

- Ryzen 7 5700x
- MSI B450 Tomahaw MAX
- MSI GTX 1080 8 GB
- 2 x 8GB Crucial Ballistix 3600 16CL
- Windows 11 64-bit

I had a Ryzen 5 3600 processor and upgraded to a Ryzen 7 5700x.

There is no inclusion of BIOS and immediately transition to the Windows screen. if at startup I click on delete and others (launching Bios), then my PC does not even go to Windows boot, the screen is just dark and nothing happens

What I tried and what didn’t help:

- updating the BIOS drivers to new ones (connecting a new cpu resets the BIOS settings to standard ones, this can be seen from the RAM speed)
- turning off the BIOS battery
- turning off the RAM and hard drive
- msi m-flash does not work with MSI.ROM and a regular boot file (immediately switches to windows boot).
- These methods did not help. BIOS ignores and does not start howtogeek.com/783790/how-to-enter-the-bios-on-windows-10
- Tried reinstalling Windows. The first time the screen did not load, the second time the load returned to its previous state (writes that it was not reinstalled due to an error)
- 7C02v3D driver was preloaded on the old 3600 processor. The bios won't load on the 5700x. BIOS settings are reset to default (RAM speed is the same)

With the old CPU it all worked.

[Dxdiag.txt](https://file.io/orcAPulVAc2W)

Comment: You can enter BIOS from Windows by holding shift when clicking "Restart". https://www.howtogeek.com/783790/how-to-enter-the-bios-on-windows-10/

Comment: do you mean you can't even get into BIOS? `turning off the RAM and hard drive` just remove the hard drive, not the RAM, your system won't POST without RAM, but without hard drive, it should just enter BIOS, where you'll probably need to turn off CSM - other than that, have you tried reverting back to the 3600? Perhaps you need to update BIOS before upgrading to 5700x

Comment: What version of BIOS do you have - you need 7C02v3D for 5700X to work